# How to export fast.ai model from Jupyter Notebook hosted on external server(google cloud compute instance)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, fast-ai

I currently using fast.ai to create machine learning models that classify images. I am using Jupyter Notebook to do my training and it is hosted on a GCP instance that I created.

---

Currently, I have finished training my model and whatnot, and I am ready to export it out of Jupyter Notebook so I can use it locally on a python file to do some image classification using predict().

```
hard_model = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet34, metrics=error_rate)
hard_model.fit_one_cycle(5)
```

So I added this line:

```
hard_model.export
```

When executed, the line above returns the chunk below. However, I can neither find a .pkl file (the intended output from the export) on my Jupyter Notebook directories nor locally in Finder.

---

So for one, am I exporting my model correctly, and more importantly, how do I export a file out from Jupyter Notebook into my local files?

```
Train: LabelList (800 items)
x: ImageList
Image (3, 224, 224),Image (3, 224, 224),Image (3, 224, 224),Image (3, 224, 224),Image (3, 224, 224)
y: CategoryList
light,light,light,light,light
Path: data/categories;

Valid: LabelList (200 items)
x: ImageList
Image (3, 224, 224),Image (3, 224, 224),Image (3, 224, 224),Image (3, 224, 224),Image (3, 224, 224)
y: CategoryList
ballsports,felines,felines,esports,water
Path: data/categories;

Test: None, model=Sequential(
  (0): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
    (1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (2): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (3): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (4): Sequential(
      (0): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (1): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (2): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (5): Sequential(
      (0): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (downsample): Sequential(
          (0): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
      (1): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (2): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (3): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (6): Sequential(
      (0): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (downsample): Sequential(
          (0): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
      (1): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (2): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (3): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (4): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (5): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (7): Sequential(
      (0): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (downsample): Sequential(
          (0): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
      (1): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (2): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
  )
  (1): Sequential(
    (0): AdaptiveConcatPool2d(
      (ap): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
      (mp): AdaptiveMaxPool2d(output_size=1)
    )
    (1): Flatten()
    (2): BatchNorm1d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (3): Dropout(p=0.25, inplace=False)
    (4): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=512, bias=True)
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): BatchNorm1d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (7): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (8): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=10, bias=True)
  )
), opt_func=functools.partial(<class 'torch.optim.adam.Adam'>, betas=(0.9, 0.99)), loss_func=FlattenedLoss of CrossEntropyLoss(), metrics=[<function error_rate at 0x7f6fcb3c83b0>], true_wd=True, bn_wd=True, wd=0.01, train_bn=True, path=PosixPath('data/categories'), model_dir='models', callback_fns=[functools.partial(<class 'fastai.basic_train.Recorder'>, add_time=True, silent=False)], callbacks=[], layer_groups=[Sequential(
  (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
  (1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (2): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (3): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (4): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (5): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (6): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (7): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (8): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (9): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (10): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (12): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (13): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (14): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (15): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (16): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (17): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (18): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (19): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (20): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (21): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (22): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (23): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (24): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
  (25): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (26): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (27): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (28): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (29): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (30): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (31): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (32): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (33): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (34): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (35): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (36): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (37): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (38): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (39): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (40): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
), Sequential(
  (0): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (2): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (3): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (4): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (5): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
  (6): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (7): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (8): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (10): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (11): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (12): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (13): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (14): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (15): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (16): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (17): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (18): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (19): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (20): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (21): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (22): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (23): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (24): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (25): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (26): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (27): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (28): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (29): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (30): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (31): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (32): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (33): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (34): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (35): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (36): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (37): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
  (38): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (39): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (40): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (41): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (42): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (43): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (44): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (45): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (46): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (47): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
  (48): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
), Sequential(
  (0): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
  (1): AdaptiveMaxPool2d(output_size=1)
  (2): Flatten()
  (3): BatchNorm1d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (4): Dropout(p=0.25, inplace=False)
  (5): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=512, bias=True)
  (6): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (7): BatchNorm1d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (8): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
  (9): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=10, bias=True)
)], add_time=True, silent=False)>
​
```

Answer (score 0):

`joblib` works very well for this. See this introductory post for details: https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/